# How to run awk command across SSH with local variables - Bash

Tags: bash, awk, ssh

I have a command which uses `awk` that I am trying to run remotely via SSH.

This is the command and a sample output when it is run locally:

```
df -h -P | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6}'

Filesystem Size Used Use% Mounted
/dev/mapper/volgroup00-lv_root 3.9G 2.7G 74% /
tmpfs 2.9G 0 0% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/volgroup00-lv_seemis 4.4G 3.6G 87% /STORE
/dev/sda1 477M 195M 44% /boot
/dev/sdb1 30G 26G 90% /data
```

The output of that command is then processed by the rest of my script. However, when I try to run the command remotely it produces an error. Here is an example of the remote command and the error it produces (where `$servername` is the FQDN of the server and `$user` is the SSH user):

```
timeout 10s ssh -n $user@$servername "df -h -P | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6}'"


awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,,}
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,,}
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,,}
awk: cmd. line:1:          ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,,}
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,,}
awk: cmd. line:1:            ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,,}
awk: cmd. line:1:             ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

I feel that this has something to do with the use of $1, $2 etc. when running the command remotely.
How can I get around this error that `awk` is producing?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a back slash before each $NUM variable fixed the problem:

```
timeout 10s ssh -n $user@$servername "df -h -P | awk '{print \$1,\$2,\$3,\$5,\$6}'"
```

The command returned what was expected.